# Business Calculus: Find the derivative of the following function...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours.

$\dfrac{9e^{2x}}{8x+3}$

I know $u'(x)$ will be $18e^{2x}$
 and $v'(x)$ will be $8$

Written out, it will be $\dfrac{(8x+3)(18e^{2x})-(9e^{2x})(8)}{(8x+3)^2}$

I get to the part above^^ and I'm not sure what to do. I know it's probably something simple that I'm over or under thinking, but please help!

Comment: What are U and v (and it seems strange to use a capital for one and lower case for the other).  It sounds like you are integrating by parts, but you didn't say that.  What is your question?

Comment: Yes this problem requires you to find the derivative. About the quotient rule, I know it more or less, but I'm just not sure how to apply it to this problem. I'm just lost.

Comment: Don't mind the uppercase U, and lower v, it has no significance, it was just a typo @RossMillikan

Comment: You have applied the quotient rule correctly, so your answer is correct for the derivative.  One thought would be that you can stop here, because you have a correct expression for the derivative.  Another thought would be that you should simplify it.  I commented on that in my answer edit.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan you've been a great help!

Comment: Pro-tip, quotient rule? WTF is that, forget it, more to remember! $\frac{u}{v}=uv^{-1}$ and use the product rule "first times derivative of second plus second times derivative of first", $-uv^{-2}\frac{dv}{dx}+v^{-1}\frac{du}{dx}$ even is hard to remember, so don't,product rule FTW.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually meant $\frac{(8x+3)(18e^{2x})-(9e^{2x})(8)}{(8x+3)^2}$ =

$\frac{(8x+3)(18e^{2x})-(18e^{2x})(4)}{(8x+3)^2}$

Factor out $18e^{2x}$ to obtain

$\frac{18e^{2x}((8x+3)-4)}{(8x+3)^2} = $

$\frac{18e^{2x}(8x-1)}{(8x+3)^2}$

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a little confused on how you got to your final answer, but I'll go back and rework it. I probably just did something careless. Thanks again!

Comment: I edited the post to add a few more steps. If you feel it useful, don't forget to click accept.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is fine.  Now you are probably expected to "simplify" it.  Simplification is often in the eye of the beholder, but you should distribute the $18e^{2x}$ in the numerator over the two terms it mulitplies, then combine one of them with the $9e^{2x} \cdot 8$.  Whether you expand the denominator or not is definitely in the eye of the beholder.  I would not unless it helped some further computation in a problem.

Comment: I feel that it's usually preferable to simplify by factoring, since there are so many times where you're solving for critical numbers, which means you have to factor it anyway.